# Updating the table row with existing data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that has around 1 million rows. The data in one of the columns is like this:

```
Table1
col1

2034/5402/1234
123/456/789/456/
786/324/654/
```

I want to append /6789 in each row. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `UPDATE Table 1 SET col1 = col1 + '/6789'`?

Comment: If you  are indexed properly, SQL will probably not allow that query without a `WHERE` clause --  IE `UPDATE Table 1 SET col1 = col1 + '/6789' WHERE id > 0`

Comment: @Zak Why would you need that WHERE clause?

Comment: I didn't say "need" I said, if it's indexed, and `--safe-updates` is turned on .. SQL Server should make a `WHERE` mandatory ..

Comment: Why does it look like you're storing delimited data in your database?

Comment: @Zak Gotcha.  Wasn't following what you meant by "indexed properly", which does imply you need that WHERE clause.  But in any case `--safe-updates` is a MySQL thing (and maybe some others), but is not a SQL Server thing.

Comment: Another side-note: SQL Server 2008 is 2.5 years past EOL.  You should _really_ look to be upgrading to a modern version.